# Error: incomplete SQL: ls

Tags: java, android, sqlite, shell, root

I am trying to access the database of another application and print it's contents to the console (USING ROOT), but for some reason I am getting this response:

```
E/[Error]: Error: incomplete SQL: ls
E/[Error]: exit
```

I don't really understand why this is happening. I tried to put my syntax in escaped quotations, I tried other sqlite commands, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

I can access the database and print it contents using ADB through my PC with the same path, and if I press the button in my application it asks me for root access, so those 2 are not the issues.

My dumbed down code:

> onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnCon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnCon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RunWithRoot("su shell -c sqlite3 \"data/data/app.package/databases/Database.db\" \"select * from messages;\"");
            }
        });
    }
```

> RunWithRoot

```
private void RunWithRoot(String textView) {
        try {
            String line;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(textView);
            OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
            InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
            InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

            stdin.write(("ls\n").getBytes());
            stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());
            stdin.flush();

            stdin.close();
            BufferedReader br =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("[Output]", line);
            }
            br.close();
            br =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("[Error]", line);
            }
            br.close();

            process.waitFor();
            process.destroy();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? I am very new to Android development, and even newer to root. If someone could throw me in the right direction with this, that would be MUCH appreciated.

PS: This app will be for personal use only, so I don't need checks to see if people have root, or if the path exists, etc.. I already heard a few developer's minds worrying heh

Comment: why are you doing `stdin.write(("ls\n").getBytes());` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Holy crap I am really really blind. Thank you! However, it says : "unable to open database "data/data/app.pkge/databases/Database.db": unable to open database file" now

Comment: Is the path correct?

Comment: BTW, don't silent swallow exceptions ` catch (Exception ex) {
        }`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks for the tip! I'll put it in a try{}catch(Exception){System.out.print(ex)} block. The path is correct 100% sure. Could we maybe take this to the chat? If you've got time for it of course.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following code.

```
private void RunWithRoot(){
    String line;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su shell");
    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

    stdin.write("su -c 'sqlite3 \"/data/data/app.pkge/databases/Database.db\" \"select * from messages;\"'\n".getBytes());
    stdin.flush();

    stdin.close();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.d("[Output]", line);
    }
    br.close();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.e("[Error]", line);
    }
    br.close();

    process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();
}
```

And now it works correctly! Mostly thanks to @ScaryWombat!